# Number of strings replaced in stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa

When using stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:, is there a way to get the number of strings that it has replaced?

Of course I could just search for the string prior to using the replace, but since the replace probably does the same search, it would be more effective to count the strings while replacing the string?

Comment: I don't think this is possible. But you could use NSScanner instead.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could use `replaceOccurrencesOfString:withString:options:range:` in the `NSMutableString` class. It replaces all occurrences of a given string in a given range with another given string and returns the number of replacements.

example:

```
NSMutableString *str = [NSMutableString stringWithString:@"my name is shams"];

NSUInteger count = [str replaceOccurrencesOfString:@"shams"
                                        withString:@"shams ahmed"
                                           options:NSCaseInsensitiveSearch
                                             range:NSMakeRange(0, str.length)];

NSLog(@"replaced count: %u", count);
```

Comment: Ah of course, NSMutableString's replace does not need to return the result string, and therefore returns the number of strings replaced. Nice, thank you!